# Flashing a White page

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, screen

I have created a website but when i navigate form one menu to another a White flash screen is showing. I google for it but not found the solution. Please help me. Its showing in all browser specially in IE9. Please help me if there any solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally happens when it is loading the next page. If the loading time is more, the white page remains longer. This is a natural behavior of IE and is not-unusual in other browsers too

Comment: Dear S.Swaroop thank you very much.Cant we prevent this? i mean background will not change. Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK, it cannot be controlled. This is the same behavior in every browser. But if you can explain a little more about your objective may be someone can come up with an alternate solution