# Node.js App : white flash on page load

Tags: node.js, express, reload, pageload

I have a very simple Node.js (express) app.

The pages are very simple, so fancy html, no iframes. I use jade to render them.
Yet when navigating from one page to another, or simply reloading the page, a white screen / flash appears for a brief moment before displaying the actual page.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563484/flashing-a-white-page) states that this behavior is normal, which is hard to believe given that none of my other websites behave like that, nor do much heavier pages.
Ex : facebook, youtube, google, wikipedia ... do not have a flashy transition when navigating between pages.

My website is pretty light :

- Page load time : 99ms
- Page size : 34.4kB

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bjTSbm/http://165.225.137.117

*Details* :
I have my app running locally as well as on a vps.

For the local version :
The white flash appears on following browsers :

- Chrome (MAC) 28.0.1500.71

But not on :

- Firefox (MAC) 16.0.1
- Safari (MAC) 6.0

---

For the vps version :
The white flash appears on following browsers :

- Chrome (MAC) 28.0.1500.71
- Safari (MAC) 6.0

But not on :

- Firefox (MAC) 16.0.1

What is the cause of this white flash and how can I solve that ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it code-related / browser-related ? Have you tested on different browsers ? How is it different from your other web sites ? Please add some meaningful details to the question.

Comment: @user568109 you are right, I added more details to the post.

Comment: Maybe chrome is overburdened. Can you test with a new profile :http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Multiple-Google-Chrome-Profiles. Browsers can get slower with time.

Comment: @user568109 Thanks a lot ! That did the trick on Chrome. But why was only my website having that behavior? Also Safari is a strange case, with the flash only showing for the vps version.

Comment: Chrome seems to have some issues on Mac. It tends to slow down considerably. Difficult to say about Safari, try cleaning it up.

Comment: @user568109 Do the white flashes also appear on your browser(s) ? [link](http://expaflyr.com)